# API-Platform, Error when doing POST. Assert trigger despite that the data is sent

Tags: api-platform.com

I have an error when I POST new data using API-Platform (Swagger/Postman). Somebody can explain?
I have a fixtures that works as expected.

```sh
curl -X POST "http://localhost:8080/countries" -H  "accept: application/json" -H  "Content-Type: application/json" -d "[{\"name\":\"Aruba2\",\"iso2\":\"ZZ\",\"iso3\":\"ZZZ\",\"region\":\"Americas\",\"subregion\":\"Caribbean\",\"capital\":\"Oranjestad\",\"latitude\":12.5,\"longitude\":-69.96666666,\"isEc\":false,\"isEfta\":false}]"
```

The Data is well structured and valid.

The Error I am receiving

```json
{
  "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-10",
  "title": "An error occurred",
  "detail": "name: The country name should not be blank\nname: The country name should not be null\niso2: The iso-2 cannot be blank\niso3: The iso-3 cannot be blank\nregion: The region cannot be blank\nsubregion: The sub-region cannot be blank\ncapital: The capital cannot be blank\nlatitude: The latitude cannot be blank\nlongitude: The longitude cannot be blank\nisEc: The field cannot be blank\nisEfta: The field cannot be blank",
  "violations": [
    {
```

This is the entity code.

```php
/**
 *
 * @ApiResource(
 *     iri="https://schema.org/Country",
 *     routePrefix="/",
 *     shortName="Countries",
 *     description="API Access to Country Entity",
 *     normalizationContext={"groups"={"country:read"}},
 *     denormalizationContext={"groups"={"country:write"}},
 *     collectionOperations={"GET","POST",
 *         "GETLIST"={
 *             "method"="GET",
 *             "description"="Retrieves a limited set of properties of Country resources",
 *             "path"="country_list_short",
 *             "normalization_context"={"groups":"country:list:short:read"}
 *         }
 *     }
 * )
 *
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=CountryRepository::class)
 *
 */
class Country extends AbstractEntity

/**
 *
 * @ORM\Column(
 *     name="name",
 *     type="string",
 *     length=128,
 *     nullable=false,
 *     options={"comment":"Country name (English)"}
 * )
 *
 * @Assert\Unique(message="The name {{ value }} already in the table")
 * @Assert\NotBlank(message="The country name should not be blank")
 * @Assert\NotNull(message="The country name should not be null")
 * @Assert\Length(
 *     min="2",
 *     minMessage="The Country name expected minimum length is {{ limit }}",
 *     max="128",
 *     maxMessage="The Country name expected maximum length is {{ limit }}"
 * )
 *
 * @Groups({"country:read","country:write","country:list:short:read"})
 */
private $name;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sending a JSON array instead of JSON object.

Just remove both prepended and appended squared brackets:

`{\"name\":\"Aruba2\",\"iso2\":\"ZZ\",\"iso3\":\"ZZZ\",\"region\":\"Americas\",\"subregion\":\"Caribbean\",\"capital\":\"Oranjestad\",\"latitude\":12.5,\"longitude\":-69.96666666,\"isEc\":false,\"isEfta\":false}`

EDIT:

Also you are using the `@Assert\Unique` annotation. This is a mistake. This annotation must be [used with collections](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Unique.html). Given the error message and your property type, you want to use [`@Assert\UniqueEntity`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/UniqueEntity.html)`, which is a class contraint checking whether the property is unique within the table.

Comment: This were it is strange too, If I remove the [] I have:
```
    {
      "propertyPath": "name",
      "message": "This value should be of type array|IteratorAggregate."
    },
```
Would it be due to the collectionOperation defnitin?

Comment: Add `@var` annotations to your properties, e.g `@var string`. Then check your getters/setters signature.

Comment: I have @var but I remove them when copying the code (the editor found it has too much code) The getter/setter signature are correct (?string, self).

`@var string The country name`

Comment: I have completed my answer.